# When running bundle exec rails webpacker:install getting this error "File unchanged! The supplied flag value not found!"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

Any suggestions on what to try here...

So when I try running:  bundle exec rake webpacker:install

abright master % rake webpacker:install

```
   identical  config/webpacker.yml
Copying webpack core config
       exist  config/webpack
   identical  config/webpack/base.js
   identical  config/webpack/development.js
   identical  config/webpack/production.js
   identical  config/webpack/test.js
The packs app source directory already exists
       apply  /Users/sammy/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-6.0.0.beta.7/lib/install/binstubs.rb
  Copying binstubs
       exist    bin
   identical    bin/webpack
   identical    bin/webpack-dev-server
File unchanged! The supplied flag value not found!  .gitignore
Installing all JavaScript dependencies [from prerelease rails/webpacker]
         run  yarn add @rails/webpacker@next from "."
yarn add v1.22.19
```

I am getting this error from the code below.

Real issue (which I think is caused by this is that

```
Webpacker can't find application.css in /Users/sammy/workspace/abright/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{ }
```

Here are version details:
1- rails webpack --version
rake, version 13.0.6

abright master % rails webpacker:info

```
Ruby: ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-darwin18]
Rails: 6.1.4
Webpacker: 6.0.0.beta.7
Node: v18.1.0
Yarn: 1.22.19

@rails/webpacker:
jpstart-app@ /Users/sammy/workspace/abright
└── @rails/webpacker@6.0.0-rc.6

Is bin/webpack present?: true
Is bin/webpack-dev-server present?: true
Is bin/yarn present?: true
```

Comment: so was able to fix - not sure exactly why I was getting the issue but did the following changes:

changed webpacker.yml

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs


base.js
************** ************** *************** *****
const { webpackConfig, merge } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const customConfig = {
  // Use cheap sourcemap generation
  devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',
  plugins: [],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.css']
  }
}
************
// module.exports = webpackConfig
module.exports = merge(webpackConfig, customConfig)